# How do I allow f.ex Color-tags while using preg_replace?

Tags: php, html, tags, bbcode

I've been working on how my users could be able to use BB-codes (html-tags) at their public profile. I'm currently using preg_replace, and it's working fine. Tho' now I want them to be able to use COLOR-tags as well, and I can't seem to find anything about it.

F.ex = `<color=#FF0000>This is a color tag</color>`

Here the color is going to be RED at their profile for others to see. How do I do this?

Thanks,

Marius

Comment: The same way you do it for your other tags ?

Comment: For some reason, I can't insert the color-tag into the function..

Comment: Try a [bbcode parser](http://jbbcode.com/) then

Comment: @MariusLøkken: Why don't you post you code so we can see why that is the case.

Comment: I think I'll just try the BBcode parser, thanks for quick response! But for the experience-sake, here is the code:

$profile_profile = htmlspecialchars($row->profile);

$profile_profile = preg_replace('#&lt;(/?(?:pre|b|u))&gt;#', '<\1>', $profile_profile);

As well as these BB-codes, I want the <color=#XXX></color> tag included.